# Функция обхода дерева классов

Tags: python, дерево, классы

```
"""
Выполняет обход дерева наследования снизу вверх, используя ссылки на пространства
имен, и отображает суперклассы с отступами
"""

def classtree(cls, indent):
    print('.' * indent + cls.__name__)
    for supercls in cls.__bases__:
       classtree(supercls, indent+3)

def instancetree(inst):
    print('Tree of', inst)
    classtree(inst.__class__, 3)

def selftest():
    class A:      pass
    class B(A):   pass
    class C(A):   pass
    class D(B,C): pass
    class E:      pass
    class F(D,E): pass

    instancetree(B())
    instancetree(F())

if __name__ == '__main__': selftest()
```

Если запустить данный код то обход дерева будет выполненн как полжено. но если добавить инструкцию return в вызов функции classtree   [*return* classtree(supercls, indent+3)],   то обход дерева выполняется не полностью. Почему так? в чем различие.

Comment: @Maksim это как? Выходить после обработки первого же значения из `cls.__bases__`?

Код приведите

Comment: Код же привел выше. Он работает как положено. т.е полностью обходит дерево классов. Я понимаю его так: при вызове instancetree(F()), выполняется несколько рекурсивных вызовов, после получения последнего значения стек вызовов опустошается и поток выполнения переходит в цикл for для обработки класса С. Но если добавить инструкцию  return этого не происходит, т.е обход дерева происходит только по одной ветке

Comment: Кож же привел выше. Он работает как положено. Я понимаю его так: при вызове  instancetree(F()) создается несколько рекурсивных вызовов. после получения последного значения стек вызовов опустошается и управление передается в цикл for для обработки класса С. Но Если добавить инструкцию return в функцию -  return classtree(supercls), indent+3), то обход будет уже выполняться по одной ветке и все

Comment: @Maksim я в приведённом выше коде никакого return'а не вижу. И куда Вы его вставляете, понять не могу. Одну гипотезу я высказал, но правильно ли я понял -- неизвестно. Если так:

    for supercls in cls.__bases__:
       return classtree(supercls, indent+3)

то это явный бред. А с телепатией у меня сегодня напряг. Да и в остальные дни не лучше.

Comment: @Maksim, вас просят привести не работающий код.

Наверное товарищ @alexlz (как и я) подозревает, что вы вставляете return в цикл

Приведите неработающий код - и будет видно что вы делаете не так

Comment: Да, именно так. а в чем тут проблема?

Comment: @Maksim Код эквивалентен следующему:

    if cls.__bases__ : return classtree(cls.__bases__[0], indent+3)

Вам именно это надо?

Comment: Нет, хочу  просто понять действия интерпретатора при рекурсивных вызовах.
т.е я правильно понимаю: при вызове instancetree(F()), выполняется несколько рекурсивных вызовов, после получения последнего значения стек вызовов опустошается и поток выполнения переходит в цикл for для обработки класса С ?. c инструкцие return я уже понял что это бред :)